# Client Socket does not read from serversocket although if i connect it through browser it outputs to it

Tags: java, socketserver

Serverpool class

```
   public class PooledWebServer implements Runnable{

   int port;
   ServerSocket Serversocket;
   Thread runningThread = null;
   boolean isStoped = false;
   ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

   public PooledWebServer(int port)
  {
   this.port = port;
  }

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized(this){
        this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
    OpenServerSocket();

    while(!isStoped()){
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = Serversocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PooledWebServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        this.threadPool.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket,"Thread Pool Server"));

    }
    this.threadPool.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Server Stopped!");
}

private void OpenServerSocket(){
   try {
       Serversocket = new ServerSocket();
       Serversocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.4",port));
       System.out.println("Server Started at 192.168.1.4");
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(PooledWebServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}

private synchronized boolean isStoped(){
    return this.isStoped;
}
public synchronized void stop()
{
    this.isStoped = true;
    try{
        this.Serversocket.close();
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
}
```

}

WorkerThread class

```
public WorkerRunnable(Socket client,String serverText){
    clientSocket = client;
    this.serverText = serverText;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try{
         BufferedReader input =new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        //OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));


            out.write(("WorkerThread started for client for address: "+clientSocket.getInetAddress())); 
            // above message is sent to client on connection
            String s = input.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client "+clientSocket.getInetAddress() +" says: "+s);



        out.close();
        input.close();


    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Client

```
public class Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JPanel pane;
JTextField message;

JButton send;

File myFile;
InputStream input;
OutputStream out;
JLabel server;

Socket client = null;

public Client()
{
    pane = new JPanel();
    server = new JLabel("Send to connect!");
    message = new JTextField();

    send = new JButton("Send");




    send.addActionListener(this);

    //connect();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    pane.add(server);
    pane.add(message);

    pane.add(send);

    this.add(pane);
    this.setSize(500, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 if(e.getSource() == send){
        sendMessage();
    }
}

void connect(){
    client = new Socket();
    try {
        client.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.4",9000));
        System.out.println("Client connected to: "+client.getLocalAddress());
        server.setText("Client connected to: "+client.getLocalAddress().toString());



    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

void sendMessage() {

    try {
           connect();    
            BufferedReader inp =new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            String s = inp.readLine(); // Program hangs here......
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));


String m = message.getText().trim(); 

            if(myFile == null){
                output.write(m);
            }else{
                   output.write(m);
            }




            output.close();
            inp.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
        try {

            client.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

}

What is wrong in it? I am new to sockets in java. I want to send message to and from server.
Here the output from server:`out.write(("WorkerThread started for client for address:          "+clientSocket.getInetAddress()));`
is not read by client.
When I connect using browser i get the message!
Is my code right or am I missing something?

Comment: type ***out.flush();*** after the ***out.wirte(...)*** :)

Comment: Not working! Still the same problem :(